# Migration of LDAP and GOsa-config to new server

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I have a running LDAP-server (using Ubuntu 12.04) with GOsa installed on it. Is there a way to migrate the whole database including the GOsa-config to a new server (Ubuntu 14.04)? I tried exporting and importing the LDAP-databases with slapcat/slapadd, but didn't succeed. When the database transfer was complete, GOsa wasn't able to connect with LDAP. I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots and lots of searching, I finally found a solution by myself in the deep internet. In case someone has the same problem in the future, I'm gonna post the answer here.

Actually, it's pretty simple. On the new server, you need to install LDAP and GOsa normally. To transfer the LDAP-database, there only two commands you need to execute. In many forums I found suggestions to use slapcat/add, but none of them worked for me. 
Instead, to get a copy of the database, run the following command on the old server (use the correct search base and admin username!):

```
 ldapsearch -z max -LLL -Wx -D "cn=admin,dc=your,dc=domain" -b "dc=your,dc=domain" > save.ldif
```

Then, transfer the file you just created to the new server, using scp, ftp or whatever. To insert the data into your new LDAP-database, run this command (again, insert your searchbase):

```
ldapmodify -c -Wx -D "cn=admin,dc=your,dc=domain" -a -f save.ldif
```

That's it!